# cv::cvtColor without allocating memory issue

Tags: android, c++, opencv, memory, memory-management

I am trying to convert a 320x240 image from NV21 into a RGBA one using cv::cvtColor, **without** allocating new memory.

So I tried various ways of achieving this. I know that cv::cvtColor calls cv::Mat.create(..) to allocate memory for the output Mat, and I've seen that cv::Mat.create(...) only allocates new memory if the size & type of the requested Mat differs from its current values.

Given, these, the following:

```
//(1)
cv::Mat frame(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, pointerToNV21Data);
//(2)
cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21);
```

Allocates a new continuous memory region of `320 * 240 * 4 channels = 307200` bytes (previously free memory), and discards the previously allocated `320 * 360 * 1 channel = 115200` bytes.

When `cv::cvtColor` internally calls `cv::Mat.create(...)`, the new memory block is allocated because:

- before `cv::cvtColor`, *frame* was a `cv::Mat` of size 320x360, with 1 channel
- `cv::cvtColor` requires it to be a `cv::Mat` of size 320x240 with 4 channels

So my most optimistic attempt to solving this was to do the following:

```
//allocate a byte buffer of 307200 bytes
uchar largeBuffer[307200];

//make sure the 115200 NV21 image bytes are written to the buffer
writeNV21DataToBuffer(largeBuffer);

//create cv::Mat that wraps "largeBuffer" as a NV21 image
cv::Mat frameNV21(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, largeBuffer);

//create a second cv::Mat that wraps around the same "largeBuffer", 
//but this time consider it as pointing to a RGBA image
cv::Mat frameRGBA(height, width, CV_8UC4, largeBuffer);

//call cv::cvtColor
cv::cvtColor(frameNV21, frameRGBA, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21);
```

By doing this, indeed no new memory is allocated. Printing `cv::Mat.dataStart` & `cv::Mat.dataStart` of `frameNV21`, `frameRGBA` before `cv::cvtColor` and `frameRGBA` after `cv::cvtColor` confirms that the same memory region was used, and that no new memory was allocated for the result.

However...the conversion itself is not done properly, the result looking like this, when displayed on the screen:

[image]

At this point, I'm out of ideas. Is my last approach inherently wrong, or is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can add a new `cvtColor` function to OpenCV and then rebuild. I think that can be the simpler way.

Comment: while that would be an option, I would prefer to not modify OpenCV itself...if it comes to that, I will most likely add the new conversion method to one of my utility classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use cvtColor without having it allocate new memory: just use a larger buffer:

```
//allocate a byte buffer of 307200 + 115200 bytes
uchar largeBuffer[307200 + 115200];

//make sure the 115200 NV21 image bytes are written to the buffer
writeNV21DataToBuffer(largeBuffer + 307200);

//create cv::Mat that wraps "largeBuffer + 307200" as a NV21 image
cv::Mat frameNV21(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, largeBuffer + 307200);

//create a second cv::Mat that wraps around the same "largeBuffer", 
//but this time consider it as pointing to a RGBA image
cv::Mat frameRGBA(height, width, CV_8UC4, largeBuffer);

//call cv::cvtColor
cv::cvtColor(frameNV21, frameRGBA, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21);
```

If your question instead was: "can I have `cvtColor` work inplace?", meaning without additional memory for storing the source bitmap, the answer is no. At least not with `cvtColor`.

The problem is that you need the data you are overwriting with `cvtColor`. In fact if everything was done sequentially, you could have just put the UV part of the image outside the RGBA data and save `width * height` bytes. (Un)fortunately OpenCV is performing cvtColor in parallel, so you will see errors at strange spots (likely you will have some correctly converted horizontal stripes and some totally wrong ones). So you will need to have a different buffer.

The conversion *can be done* inplace, but is much more slow, since you will need to rearrange your data.

Comment: I also though the weird output could be caused because the original data was overwritten by the converted data, hints of this were in the repetitive pattern of the output itself...but I wasn't sure of how `cvtColor` operates exactly, and in consequence, if this was actually the case. 
I just tested your answer, it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a comment than an answer however I couldnot fir it in a comment. So here we go:
I have no NV21 encoder in OpenCV it can only decode, so i tried this code:

```
cv::Mat ssOrg = cv::imread( "/home/user/ss.png");

cv::Mat ssGray;
cv::cvtColor( ssOrg, ssGray, CV_BGR2YUV_I420);
cv::resize( ssGray, ssGray, cv::Size(320, 360));

uchar largeBuffer[307200];
cv::Mat frameNV21( 360, 320, CV_8UC1, largeBuffer);
cv::Mat frameRGBA( 320, 240, CV_8UC4, largeBuffer);

const uchar * nv21Ptr = ssGray.ptr();
for ( int i = 0; i < 360 * 320; ++i){
    largeBuffer[i] = *nv21Ptr++;
}
cv::cvtColor(frameNV21, frameRGBA, CV_YUV2BGRA_I420);
cv::imshow( "rgb", frameRGBA);

cv::waitKey();
```

This code did work, so I think your approach is correct. However when I changed the line `cv::cvtColor(frameNV21, frameRGBA, CV_YUV2BGRA_I420);` to `cv::cvtColor(frameNV21, frameRGBA, CV_YUV2BGRA_NV21);` I got some artifacts on the image. Can you check if you can convert back from NV21 format? Also I am testing on PC and you are testing on android.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. I ran some tests with this code PC, on a separate project...I appreciate your help, but there are a few things wrong with it.

First, `cv::Mat frameRGBA( 320, 240,...);` should actually be `cv::Mat frameRGBA( 240, 320,...);` (i.e. rows & cols should be reversed), since the rows give the height, and the cols the width.

Because they were in the wrong order, when calling cv::cvtColor in your sample, a new memory allocation was performed anyway, since OpenCV saw it needed a (240, 320) size Mat, whereas frameRGBA was defined as being a (320, 240) Mat

Comment: Actually this seems to be the problem, while writing out `( 240, 320)` the output was a mess, so I thought I misremembered the sizes so I changed it to `( 320, 240)`. I currently tested and it works with my wrong size and with correct size result is just like yours.

Comment: Because of the new allocation, this also meant that conversion wasn't performed over the same single mem location, and that's why it worked in your tests (and in my initial tests, until I saw the wrong size being declared)


I get the same result when converting from YUVI420 back to RGBA/BGRA (whichever is needed, the result is the same) on PC, as on Android. This basically also confirms what @CostantinoGrana said in his answer (i.e. that conversion can't happen over the same memory space). 


The artifacts you got when conv from NV21 were because NV21 isn't fully compatible with YUVI420